# Webrick Rails server won't start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I'm using Rails 4.0.0, and successfully installed the mysql2 gem yesterday (mysql-0.3.15) using mysql-connector-c-6.1.3.winx64. I created a new Rails project called "simple_cms" using `rails new simple_cms -d mysql` which worked, and then ran `bundle install` which was also fine.

When I try to run `rails server` I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Hans>cd sites

C:\Users\Hans\Sites>cd simple_cms

C:\Users\Hans\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in
`requir e': 126: The specified module could not be found.   -
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/ge
ms/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.15/mysql2/mysql2.so
(LoadError)

        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb :8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.0.rc2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Hans/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

C:\Users\Hans\Sites\simple_cms>
```

What can I do about this?  By the way, the module it cannot find is in fact there.

28-Mar-2014  After all the problems I had installing and re-installing, I still could not get rails server to run. As I mainly want this installation to learn Ruby on Rails, I have instead installed the Bitnami Ruby stack, which installs everything automatically. This seems to work fine, and I've got Ruby, MySQL and the Apache Web Server working.

Comment: `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: have you made sure that your database is installed properly ? ..you can check with `rails db` to check it connecting to database mysql properly.

Comment: with bundle exec rails server I get the same error.

Comment: with rails db I get:                                          C:\Users\Hans\Sites\simple_cms>rails dbconsole
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

C:\Users\Hans\Sites\simple_cms>

Comment: Post the contents of your config/database.yml file

Comment: I am going to first un-install everything and start from scratch. Maybe this weekend. Thanks for your help Eugene and Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems configuring the Lynda course on learning Ruby on Rails.  I found an additional step that seemed to work for me.  Since the error was complaining about the lack of a database in mysql, I created the missing database and that fixed the problem.

Log into mysql as root and prompt for password:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then:

```
SHOW DATABASES;

CREATE DATABASE simple_cms_development; 

exit;
```